# Implicit Animation of Blur or Other Brush Effect

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I'm trying to create implicit hide and show animations that contain a blur.  I have the following code to do a Gaussian Blur animation, but I don't know how to add it to a CompositionAnimationGroup and use it as an implicit animation. I only know how to start an animation using the SpriteVisual.

```
public static void CompositionAnimationBlur(UIElement element, int durationMilliseconds)
{
    var visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(element);
    var compositor = visual.Compositor;

    var effect = new GaussianBlurEffect()
    {
        Name = "Blur",
        Source = new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("EffectSource"),
        BlurAmount = 0f,
        BorderMode = EffectBorderMode.Hard,
    };

    var blurEffectFactory = compositor.CreateEffectFactory(effect, new[] { effect.Name + "." + nameof(effect.BlurAmount) });
    var brush = blurEffectFactory.CreateBrush();
    var destinationBrush = compositor.CreateBackdropBrush();
    brush.SetSourceParameter("EffectSource", destinationBrush);

    var sprite = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
    sprite.Size = new Vector2((float)(element.RenderSize.Width), (float)(element.RenderSize.Height));
    sprite.Brush = brush;

    var anim = compositor.CreateScalarKeyFrameAnimation();
    anim.InsertKeyFrame(0.0f, 0f);
    anim.InsertKeyFrame(1.0f, 50f);
    anim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(durationMilliseconds);
    ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(element, sprite);
    sprite.Brush.Properties.StartAnimation("Blur.BlurAmount", anim);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For you scenario, although you could add blur animation to `CompositionAnimationGroup` like the following, you can not start **AnimationGroup** in the element visual correctly. Because the blur animation apply to the sprite brush and the fade animation apply to element visual.

```
public static void CompositionAnimationBlur(UIElement element, int durationMilliseconds)
{
    var visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(element);          
    var compositor = visual.Compositor;
    var AnimationGroup = compositor.CreateAnimationGroup();

    var effect = new GaussianBlurEffect()
    {
        Name = "Blur",
        Source = new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("EffectSource"),
        BlurAmount = 0f,
        BorderMode = EffectBorderMode.Hard,
    };

    var blurEffectFactory = compositor.CreateEffectFactory(effect, new[] { effect.Name + "." + nameof(effect.BlurAmount) });
    var brush = blurEffectFactory.CreateBrush();
    var destinationBrush = compositor.CreateBackdropBrush();
    brush.SetSourceParameter("EffectSource", destinationBrush);

    var sprite = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
    sprite.Size = new Vector2((float)(element.RenderSize.Width), (float)(element.RenderSize.Height));
    sprite.Brush = brush;

    var anim = compositor.CreateScalarKeyFrameAnimation();
    anim.InsertKeyFrame(0.0f, 0f);
    anim.InsertKeyFrame(1.0f, 50f);
    anim.Target = "Blur.BlurAmount";
    anim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(durationMilliseconds);
    ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(element, sprite);
    AnimationGroup.Add(anim);

    sprite.Brush.Properties.StartAnimationGroup(AnimationGroup);
}
```

I suggest that you could use [**UWP Community Toolkit**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/) to integrate fade and blur animations.

```
await MyRec.Blur(value: 10, duration: 1000, delay: 0).Fade(value: 0.0f, duration: 1000, delay: 0).StartAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks, I use the Toolkit and its abstracted animation syntax a lot and it's wonderful, but it doesn't allow me to attach implicit show and hide animations to a UIElement.

Comment: Have you checked this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/animations/implicitanimations)?

Comment: I have. You can add Scalar or Vector3 animations and target Opacity, Scale, and Translate.  But how can you target an effects brush like blur or saturation?